# Check if rpm is installed with ruby script

Tags: ruby, rpm

I'm trying to rewrite some bash scripts and one of the sections checks if certain rpm's are installed on the system with a basic if statement

```
if rpm -qa | grep rpmnamehere; then
     do stuff
```

I want to do something similar in ruby, but am pretty new to this and not sure where to look in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke shell command in ruby script, and save output in variable

```
a = %x{rpm -qa | grep rpmnamehere}
puts a
```

or only invoke command

```
`rpm -qa | grep rpmnamehere`
```

so, I think you can solve your problem like this

```
unless `rpm -qa | grep rpmnamehere`.empty?
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in ruby code:

```
if system "rpm -qa | grep rpmnamehere"
   #additional ruby statements
end
```

the system call will return true or false depend if the system command is successful or not.

Comment: I find this a bit cleaner, and i guess it is rather secure to rely on that grep gives proper exit codes.